# how I can use object in my file from another file (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent, android-activity

Hello I want to call an object(username, name, posts) from  Mainactivity.java to Main2Activity.java
first layout: The user enter write here name, username and posts and click on the button
second layout: the information the user has given is displayed on the page
I want to save the name, username and posts to used in Second layout

https://ibb.co/BfsKMgf

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String username;
    public String name;
    public String posts;
    EditText usernameinput;
    EditText nameinput;
    EditText postsinput;
    Button confirme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        usernameinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        nameinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        postsinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.posts);
        confirme = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirme);
        username = usernameinput.getText().toString();

        confirme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                name = nameinput.getText().toString();
                posts = postsinput.getText().toString();

                Intent otheractivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(otheractivity);
                finish();

                showToast(name);
                showToast(username);
                showToast(posts);


            }
        });



    }


    private void showToast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to pass data from one activity to second activity for example using **Intent** to pass data from one activity to another,another way use **sharedpreference** to store data and get it anywhere, third store data in **static variable**

using intent to pass data

**MainActivity.java**

```
  nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_et);
    mobileEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_et);
    submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name=nameEt.getText().toString();
            mobile_number=mobileEt.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",name);
            intent.putExtra("mobile",mobile_number);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
    mobileTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_tv);

    String name,mobile_number;
    //get Intent data
    name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    mobile_number=getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");
    nameTv.setText(name);
    mobileTv.setText(mobile_number);
```

using static variable

**MainActivity.java**
     public static String name;
     public static String mobile_number;

```
 nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_et);
    mobileEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_et);
    submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name=nameEt.getText().toString();
            mobile_number=mobileEt.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
    mobileTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_tv);
 nameTv.setText(MainActivity.name);
 mobileTv .setText(MainActivity.mobile_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

using intent to pass data from one activity to another activity or if you can use fragment then use bundle.
follow these tutorials - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java

you have to change the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("key1","editetextvalue")
intent.putStringExtra("key2","editetextvalue2")
startActivity(intent);

and get value in a second activity.
Intent intent = getIntent();
String key = intent.getStringExtra("key1")

please remember if you pass these key exact same get key other not get
```